# icacls - Integrity level is not apply on the exe file

Tags: process-explorer, icacls

I have an `exe` file that run as `Medium` integrity by default. I tried to change its integrity to `Low` with the following statament :

```
icacls 1.exe  /L
```

The output message show its succeed :

```
1.exe BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(M)
      BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
      BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
      BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

But while running it already has the same integrity in *Process Explorer* (I mean `Medium`).

How can i change an `exe` integrity to `Low`, `Medium` or `High`?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
 icacls 1.exe /setintegritylevel Low
```

Comment: It give me `1.exe: Access is denied.`

Comment: If you are running applications that are not trustworthy, I suggest also looking at [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/).

Comment: Are you running as Admin?

Comment: Yes i run as admin, but it always has `High` integrity

Comment: Now what can i do? please help me, i need it...

Comment: It works for me on Windows 10. It might be a problem with the way you are looking at it. See [this](https://malwaretips.com/threads/how-to-know-your-applications-integrity-level.57858/).

Comment: + 1 and accept from me...

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode).

Comment: is there just 3 integrity? (low, medium, high) or are still?

Comment: Just 3 for non-system applications.